# Difficulty deleting registry keys under HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR

Tags: windows-registry

We are able to create and delete other registry keys but unable to delete subkeys under `HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR`. We've tried it on Windows 10 Enterprise where we are in the Administrators group as well as a command prompt and regedit in administrator mode. We have also tried it on Windows 10 Home editions but to no avail.

Has anyone else run into this? Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Chnage the permissions on the key in question so Administrators have proper permissions. Your attempting to delete a key that normally not owed by the Administrator group. So I wouldn’t be shocked it will cause problems if you delete it

Comment: I do not have that key (2 Windows 10 Pro, 1 Windows 11 Pro). What is it for?

Comment: I DO have two sets of keys there for two different devices.  I *could* take ownership but I am going to choose not to mess with them.  No offense.. but out of curiosity.. WTF are you doing d*king with that registry key (of all keys)?  Again.. not criticizing.. just TOTALLY CURIOUS. :)

Comment: Apparently it is a list of devices plugged into the computer.  I use USB but do not have the keys. It may depend on the particular computer.   https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/window-registry

Comment: i checked the permissions on both the personal laptop and company laptop and by all accounts the admin group HAS full control over those keys...

@SeñorCMasMas my interesting in these keys is due to the fact that one of the regulatory companies we use thinks these keys could be an indicator of a possible exfiltration of data...

Comment: @John, not on my machine at least.  It is a reflection of some old crap USB drive that hasn't been plugged in in months. This "used to" be the mechanism that all USB drives used to cache connection information but I have to wonder if now that it is isolated to USB 2.0 devices?  I only see two entries and they are my only USB 2.0 drives.. hrrrmmm.. inquiring minds want to know.  OH.. @MikeMurphy, try going into device manager, show hidden devices, drives.. delete there.  If not work, set variable `devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1` try again.  But I see you have an answer.

Comment: i had this cross posted and here is what was said in another thread... just thought it was useful... "only system (S-1-5-18) have full access to Properties subkey. you need enable SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE and SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE first in token (if you have this) and use REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE when open key"

Answer (score 1):

@John's link is my answer because that tool is amazing and will ultimately be part of my solution. thanks for all the advice!

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/window-registry

Comment: I cleaned up the post and posted it. Hopefully you will provide an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Under the key `Enum\USBSTOR` a dynamic list of devices plugged into the computer is shown. I use USB but do not have the keys. It may depend on the particular computer.

It also may not be on my machine because of cleanups and/or no USB errors.

Here is a good article on the USBSTOR properties

[USBSSTOR (Science Direct Topics)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/window-registry)

> Connected USB Devices Windows® keeps a history of all connected USB
> removable storage devices (thumb drives, iPods, digital cameras,
> external HDD, etc.). This information is vital to know which devices
> were previously (or currently) connected to the suspect’s machine and
> by which user.
>
> Windows® stores USB history-related information using five registry
> keys, and each one offers a different set of information about the
> connected device. When combining this information, investigators can
> formulate a clear view of how a suspect has used removable storage to
> commence an incident.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain **PsExec** utility from [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), This allows you to run a process with with System permissions.

You can use it to run RegEdit as System and manually delete mentioned keys in the registry, use the following cmd command:

```
PsExec.exe -s -d -i "C:\Windows\regedit.exe"
```

- **-s**    Run the remote process in the System account.
- **-d**    Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive).
- **-i**    Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session. This flag is required when attempting to run console applications interactively (with redirected standard IO).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).